# How to simplify expressions in a polynomial ring using software Maple

Tags: maple

![How to simplify expressions in a polynomial ring using software Maple][1].

For example,I want to verify some expressions is zero. But I don't know how to archive my goal.

Anyone can help me? Thank you very very very very much!

I paste the expressions I want to simplify. (I can't paste images,I'm so sad!)

Expressions such as:

$$-q^{3p}(s(1-q^i))(1-q^{2i})-sq^{3p+i}-2sq^{(2i+3p)}+sq^{3p+4i}-sq^{3p+5i} +(s(1-q^i))(1-q^{2i})q^{2i+3p}+sq^{3p}+2sq^{3p+3i}$$

Comment: right click on expression,from menu choose "Simplify" , from submenu choose "Simplify"...

Answer (score 1):

Note that squiggle-brackets are Maple's set constructor, not expression delimiters. You probably want round-brackets instead. Also, use explicit multiplication signs, to avoid confusion such as between products like s*q and compound names like sq. The `simplify` command handles this example directly. You can call the command by typing it, or you can right-click on the expression as output and apply it from the pop-up context-menu.

```
expr:=-q^(3*p)*(s*(1-q^i))*(1-q^(2*i))-s*q^(3*p+i)
  -2*s*q^(2*i+3*p)+s*q^(3*p+4*i)-s*q^(3*p+5*i)
  +(s*(1-q^i))*(1-q^(2*i))*q^(2*i+3*p)+s*q^(3*p)
  +2*s*q^(3*p+3*i):

simplify(expr);
                           0
```